# Interaction term in OLS vs Linear Mixed Model

Tags: regression, mixed-model

In a study, we are trying to predict D.V. 'Y' from seven I.V., all of which are continuous variable. The measurement of 'Y' was carried out four times, in different season. I.V. on the other hand, stay static.

The hypothesis is that effect of I.V. on 'Y' varies with season. I have been studying how to model this :

Option 1:
Use dummy variable & interaction term in OLS setting, i.e.
Y = B0 + B1X1 + B2Dummy2 + B3Dummy3 + B4X1Dummy2 + B5X1Dummy3 + e

Option 2:
Use Mixed effect model. If I am understanding it correctly, this is a case of crossed mixed effect model where seasons are what is refereed in literature as 'groups'.

My question is which approach is better for modelling such data?

Comment: I am not sure but your description implies that season is one of your IV's. It should be since y depends on season

Comment: If you want my opinion, you may use numerous models for regression. The question is which produces the best outcome, which produces the smallest residuals etc. This will depend on your data, and you will not be able to know until you perform the estimations for each model.